# How to get the specific json object from laravel blade?

Tags: php, json, laravel

I am trying to get specific object from the array which is call **previous_position_1_name**,right now in my blade

> {{$jobseeker - > jobseeker['Myprevious_position_1']}}

it output the json array like:

```
{
"id": 3,
"previous_position_1_name": "QC",
"created_at": null,
"updated_at": null
}
```

I just only want to get the **previous_position_1_name** column which is **QC**.
Please guide me.

Comment: [Decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) your JSON string to an object or an array, and get what you need then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json_decode and then fetch  the certain object u want in this case it's previous_position_1_name.

```
//Decode the json so you can access the objects.. (array)
$json = json_decode($jobseeker,true);
//Access the object you want
$previous_position_1_name = $json['previous_position_1_name'];
```

Comment: thanks bro, i tried like this,and it was okie "<?php $pp1=json_decode($jobseeker->jobseeker['Myprevious_position_1'],true); ?>{{ $pp1['previous_position_1_name']}} "